# Derivations of algebraic independence

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, lie-algebras, differential-forms, differential-algebra

I was wondering if this is this is true or not:

If $D$ is a derivation and $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are algebraically independent, and $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a homogeneous polynomial with all of its monomials being relatively prime (i.e. there is no common divisor between any two of them). Is it true that the minimum $i$ such that $D^i p = 0$ is the minimum $i$ such that ALL of those monomials are $0$?

If yes, how can this be proved? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: It seems that none of these tags is relevant for this question.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I thought that this question is related to the notion of derivations studied in differential geometry and lie theory. Do you have another good suggestion for the tags? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you provide a definition of a derivation, the problem is purely of algebraic nature, so something like "abstract-algebra" or "polynomials" could be more suitable, in my opinion.

Comment: You're right, a notion like this appears in differential geometry, but it doesn't make it geometric (and if you restrict to polynomials, you can also forget about limit-based derivatives).